# Merging Framemaker files in Git

Tags: git, framemaker

We have a framemaker project with several books and we use Git to store the .fm files.
We have a situation where version 1 is already released and I have started working on version 2 and made a bunch of changes. version 2 is not yet ready to be released though.
In this state, the clients have asked for a bunch of changes to version 1. I have a copy of version 1 and so I can make those changes. However, without having to manually redo those in version 2, is it possible to merge the 2 versions? Since framemaker files are binary files, I guess I cannot.. Is that right?

Comment: Perhaps you could use MIF output format, which might be easier to do text-based comparison and _possibly_ merge the two changes? Of course, it's risky if you don't know the underlying format.

Comment: Side note: That's why *TeX* is still the best! Morale: choose better instruments next time.

Comment: So, it is not possible to merge like we merge flat files like txt, html, etc. right? I have to manually make those changes once again in version 2? (unless I possibly save both versions in an MIF format and then compare)?